# How to get absolute path to asset file?

Tags: plugin-development, assets, assetfilemodel

I have some csv files uploaded as assets and now I need to `fopen()` them from my plugin.

I have an `AssetFileModel` but I have not been able to work out how to construct a full path to the file.

I can access the filename like: `$asset->filename` which gives me `my_csv_file.csv` but this is not enough for `fopen()` to find it.

How can I get the absolute path to the asset file?

Or at least a path that I can use with `fopen()` to find the file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the rest of the path from your asset's source and folder, I think something like this should do it:

```
$source = $asset->getSource();

if ($source->type != 'Local')
{
    throw new Exception(Craft::t('Paths not available for non-local asset sources'));
}

$sourcePath = $source->settings['path'];
$folderPath = $asset->getFolder()->path;

$assetFilePath = $sourcePath.$folderPath.$asset->filename;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( it results in `{basePath}uploads/example.png` which isn't a valid path obviously

Comment: @Stalinko You can use craft()->config->parseEnvironmentString() to replace `{basePath}` with the config basePath like this `$assetFilePath = craft()->config->parseEnvironmentString($sourcePath.$folderPath.$asset->filename);`

Comment: thanks @K.Rijpstra but I haven't been working with craft cms since 2018 :))

Answer (score 12):

### Update for Craft 3:

To get the same output as Mike's path above, you can use:

```
$volumePath = $asset->getVolume()->settings['path'];
$folderPath = $asset->getFolder()->path;
$assetFilePath = Yii::getAlias($volumePath) . $folderPath . $asset->filename;
```

Comment: This may only work for assets at the top-level of an asset volume. Apt to need an intermediate `$folderPath = $asset->getFolder()->path;`, like the Craft 2 answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach in Craft 4.
This approach assumes you have an asset element ([craft\elements\Asset](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-elements-asset.html#public-properties)).

```
use Craft;
//$asset = craft\elements\Asset;
$fsPath = Craft::getAlias($asset->getVolume()->fs->path);
$attachment = $fsPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $asset->getPath();
```

Answer (score 4):

See `Asset::getImageTransformSourcePath()` for how Craft CMS resolves the real local path. (https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/elements/Asset.php#L1200)

Should look something like this:

```
$volume = $this->getVolume();
$assetFilePath = $volume instanceof LocalVolumeInterface
  ? FileHelper::normalizePath($volume->getRootPath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->getPath())
  : null;
```